# How ot fetch multiple images from multiple folders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using this but it is returning folders not images inside them.

```
path = "C://Users//Administrator//Face matcher//img//*"
for folder in glob.glob(path):
    for file in glob.glob(folder):
        print(file)
```

Comment: look for *.png for png.. for example

Comment: did not understand what are you trying to say

Comment: `path = "C://Users//Administrator//Face matcher//img//*"` finds everything in img folder .... `path = "C://Users//Administrator//Face matcher//img//*.png"` would find png only

Comment: inside img there are two folders images and images 1 and i want to fetch images from both the folders

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your directory structure is

```
    /path
         /subfolder1
            /1.png
            /2.png
         /subfolder2
            /3.png
            /4.png
```

You can try the following snippet if your subfolder have images as well sub folders

```
 path = "C://Users//Administrator//Face matcher//img//*"

 for folder in glob.glob(path ,recursive=True):
        for file in glob.glob(folder +'//*.png', recursive=True): 
             print(file)
```

*.png if in case the images are png, can replace png with other formats which you have been using.

If your subfolder have only images.

```
 path = "C://Users//Administrator//Face matcher//img//*"

 for folder in glob.glob(path ,recursive=True):
        for file in glob.glob(folder +'//*.*', recursive=True): 
             print(file)
```

Comment: for folder in glob.glob(path + ,recursive=True):
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax showing error on ,

Comment: Can you try glob.glob(path ,recursive=True)